Select and group results by dynamic date
I have to make a query on a table for time-framed report based on starting and ending date.
I want it to group by day if the date difference is less than a month, group by month if the date difference is less than a year, finally group by year if the date difference is more than a year, with all of them the time frame should be selected to.
If the time difference is less than a month, the query must group the results between each day together (eg: a row from '2022-11-04 22:01' and another from '2022-11-04 10:57' should be groupped), if it was less than a year, the rows between each month should be groupped together (eg: a row from '2024-01-06' and another from '2024-01-27' should be groupped), if it was more than a year, then the results between each year should be groupped (eg: a row from '2019-12-09' and another '2019-06-01' should be groupped)
for example with this query, i get these results:
SELECT
  *
FROM
  ViewSell
WHERE
  branchId = 1
ORDER BY
  createdAt ASC




id
branchId
totalPrice
createdAt




85
1
2718.66
2022-07-03 08:49:27.727


26
1
3832.69
2022-07-06 09:08:06.880


89
1
9569.85
2022-07-07 04:13:09.230


80
1
1523.62
2022-07-07 04:38:29.313


15
1
2500.21
2022-07-11 09:01:05.183


5
1
6874.03
2022-07-14 23:54:05.590


45
1
9188.03
2022-07-17 05:35:48.560


98
1
4426.17
2022-07-21 17:35:31.617


54
1
3862.86
2022-07-22 05:18:28.553


70
1
5668.82
2022-07-22 06:12:33.867


65
1
3653.67
2022-07-26 08:29:03.587



because the date difference is less than a month, my results should be:



branchId
sumTotalPrice
timeFrame




1
2718.66
2022-07-03


1
3832.69
2022-07-06


1
11093.47
2022-07-07


1
2500.21
2022-07-11


1
6874.03
2022-07-14


1
9188.03
2022-07-17


1
4426.17
2022-07-21


1
9531.68
2022-07-22


1
3653.67
2022-07-26



but with this query i get these results:
SELECT
  *
FROM
  ViewSell
WHERE
  branchId = 4
ORDER BY
  createdAt ASC




id
branchId
totalPrice
createdAt




52
4
7502.97
2023-11-01 17:49:51.110


56
4
7337.75
2023-11-06 15:38:57.567


44
4
9385.97
2024-01-18 11:19:04.460



So because the the date difference is less than a year, my results should be:



branchId
sumTotalPrice
timeFrame




4
9385.97
2024-01-01


4
14840.72
2023-11-01



and lastly with this query i get these results:
SELECT
  *
FROM
  ViewSell
WHERE
  branchId = 2
ORDER BY
  createdAt ASC




id
branchId
totalPrice
createdAt




22
2
5589.39
2020-05-23 15:22:14.703


46
2
6103.08
2020-08-18 03:58:14.973


48
2
4905.96
2020-10-14 23:57:48.680


85
2
8953.03
2021-08-15 11:16:34.627


6
2
8132.46
2021-08-26 21:27:21.627


53
2
1913.24
2021-09-20 17:41:13.793


4
2
3164.81
2022-03-18 04:24:40.840


28
2
3506.16
2022-05-20 17:48:44.330


37
2
7256.73
2022-07-25 20:45:16.497


16
2
7470.38
2023-01-22 18:33:07.163


27
2
5957.58
2023-03-22 03:04:02.687


99
2
7722.43
2023-04-14 21:22:38.160


81
2
4517.39
2023-04-25 11:25:17.900


70
2
5562.04
2023-05-10 08:19:35.200


55
2
9343.17
2023-11-17 08:56:09.870


94
2
1056.38
2024-01-03 18:36:24.743


47
2
8434.11
2024-03-23 09:07:31.743



so because the date difference is more than a year, my results should be:



branchId
sumTotalPrice
timeFrame




2
16598.43
2020-01-01


2
18998.73
2021-01-01


2
13927.7
2022-01-01


2
40572.99
2023-01-01


2
9490.49
2024-01-01



Here is a dbfiddle with the datas: https://dbfiddle.uk/zEOiuSIp

2023-11-06 15:38:57.567 and 2024-01-18 11:19:04.460 are less than a year apart, so why aren't they grouped together?

@ThomA the result is grouped by month, because the time difference is less than a year

@ThomA pay attention to the timeFrame field, the dates are parted by the month

So your point(s) about grouping if the dates are less than year part is irrelevant? Such as "finally group by year if the date difference is more than a year". If so, you should remove those parts.

so bassically what i want is group the results by day if the time difference is less than a month, up by month if it is less than a year, then group by year if it is more than a year

@ThomA if the time difference is less than a month, the query must group the results between each day together (eg: a row from '2022-11-04 22:01' and another from '2022-11-04 10:57' should be groupped), if it was less than a year, the rows between each month should be groupped together (eg: a row from '2024-01-06' and another from '2024-01-27' should be groupped), if it was more than a year, then the results between each year should be groupped (eg: a row from '2019-12-09' and another '2019-06-01' should be groupped)

Are you wanting this behavior to change on a branch by branch basis even when multiple branches appear or should it just reflect the span across the entire data? None of your examples show multiple branches and yet the accepted solution involves a join that treats them individually.

@Rawand Please accept an answer, I suggest Andrews since thats what formed the basis for your own.

@DaleK i can accept tomorrow, but i cant tag andrew with @ i dont know why

Why do you want to tag them? Just comment on their answer and they will get notified.

Any thoughts on my question about multiple branchids in the same report?

@shawnt00 sorry i didn't see that, yes i want it for multiple branches because some of our customers have more than one branch

@Rawand So then the question is whether you determine the timeframe groupings based on the report as a whole or looking at each branch's data individually.

@shawnt00 i want to get the result for all, but the time frame is for each branch individually, check out the answer i added

Which is what I pointed out on the comment multiple days ago.

Thanks to @andrew, I was able to achieve the result with a modification to their answer.
Here is how I did it:
WITH
  timeDifference AS (
    SELECT
      branchId,
      MIN(CAST(createdAt AS DATE)) AS startdate,
      MAX(CAST(createdAt AS DATE)) AS enddate
    FROM
      viewSell
    GROUP BY
      branchid
  ),
  timeFormat AS (
    SELECT
      VS.branchId,
      totalPrice,
      CASE
        WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, TD.startdate, TD.enddate) < 1 THEN CAST(VS.createdAt AS DATE)
        WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, TD.startdate, TD.enddate) < 1
        OR (
          DATEDIFF(YEAR, TD.startdate, TD.enddate) >= 1
          AND DATEDIFF(MONTH, TD.startdate, TD.enddate) <= 12
        )
        THEN CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, VS.createdAt), 0) AS DATE)
        WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, TD.startdate, TD.enddate) >= 1 THEN CAST(DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, createdAt), 0) AS DATE)
      END AS timeFrame
    FROM
      ViewSell AS VS
      INNER JOIN timeDifference AS TD ON VS.branchId = TD.branchId
  )
SELECT
  branchId,
  SUM(totalPrice) AS sumTotalPrice,
  timeFrame
FROM
  timeFormat
WHERE
  branchId = 2
GROUP BY
  branchId,
  timeFrame
ORDER BY
  timeFrame ASC

And another way with less CTE but harder to read:
WITH
  timeDifference AS (
    SELECT
      branchId,
      MIN(CAST(createdAt AS DATE)) AS startdate,
      MAX(CAST(createdAt AS DATE)) AS enddate
    FROM
      viewSell
    GROUP BY
      branchid
  )
SELECT
  VS.branchId,
  SUM(totalPrice) AS sumTotalPrice,
  CASE
    WHEN DATEDIFF (MONTH, TD.startdate, TD.enddate) < 1 THEN CAST(VS.createdAt AS DATE)
    WHEN DATEDIFF (YEAR, TD.startdate, TD.enddate) < 1
    OR (
      DATEDIFF (YEAR, TD.startdate, TD.enddate) >= 1
      AND DATEDIFF (MONTH, TD.startdate, TD.enddate) <= 12
    ) THEN CAST(
      DATEADD (MONTH, DATEDIFF (MONTH, 0, VS.createdAt), 0) AS DATE
    )
    WHEN DATEDIFF (YEAR, TD.startdate, TD.enddate) >= 1 THEN CAST(
      DATEADD (yy, DATEDIFF (yy, 0, createdAt), 0) AS DATE
    )
  END AS timeFrame
FROM
  ViewSell AS VS
  INNER JOIN timeDifference AS TD ON VS.branchId = TD.branchId
WHERE
  VS.branchId = 1
GROUP BY
  VS.branchId,
  CASE
    WHEN DATEDIFF (MONTH, TD.startdate, TD.enddate) < 1 THEN CAST(VS.createdAt AS DATE)
    WHEN DATEDIFF (YEAR, TD.startdate, TD.enddate) < 1
    OR (
      DATEDIFF (YEAR, TD.startdate, TD.enddate) >= 1
      AND DATEDIFF (MONTH, TD.startdate, TD.enddate) <= 12
    ) THEN CAST(
      DATEADD (MONTH, DATEDIFF (MONTH, 0, VS.createdAt), 0) AS DATE
    )
    WHEN DATEDIFF (YEAR, TD.startdate, TD.enddate) >= 1 THEN CAST(
      DATEADD (yy, DATEDIFF (yy, 0, createdAt), 0) AS DATE
    )
  END
ORDER BY
  timeFrame ASC

Here is a dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/Z2HvPd0j

The incredibly ugly way I'd do this is to:

for each branchid, determine how many days are between min and max createdAt.
Use that to derive a value that we can group by.

WITH
  daysbetween AS (
    SELECT
      branchid,
      DATEDIFF(DAY, startdate, enddate) AS daysdiff
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          branchid,
          MIN(createdAt) AS startdate,
          MAX(createdAt) AS enddate
        FROM
          viewSell
        GROUP BY
          branchid
      ) t
  )
SELECT
  branchid,
  grouper,
  SUM(totalPrice)
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      viewsell.*,
      daysbetween.daysdiff,
      CASE
        WHEN daysdiff > 365 THEN CAST(DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, createdAt), 0) AS DATE)
        WHEN daysdiff <= 30 THEN CAST(createdAt AS DATE)
        WHEN daysdiff <= 365 THEN CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, createdAt), 0) AS DATE)
      END AS grouper
    FROM
      viewsell
      INNER JOIN daysbetween ON viewsell.branchid = daysbetween.branchid
  ) t
WHERE
  branchid = 1
GROUP BY
  branchid,
  grouper

https://dbfiddle.uk/GhwE4tcA

I cannot for the life of me get this query to format properly.

I have used your method with this new query, can you check it out and tell me if it works better? https://dbfiddle.uk/1DXMJie-

Something like this perhaps?
SELECT  branchid, SUM(totalPrice) as total, convert(datetime, cast(diff as varchar(10))) as dt
FROM    (
    SELECT  *
    ,   CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, min(createdAt) OVER(partition BY branchid), max(createdAt) OVER(partition BY branchid)) >= 365 THEN year(createdAt) * 10000 + 101
        WHEN DATEDIFF(day, min(createdAt) OVER(partition BY branchid), max(createdAt) OVER(partition BY branchid)) >= 28 THEN year(createdAt) * 10000 + MONTH(createdAt) * 100 + 1
        ELSE year(createdAt) * 10000 + month(createdAt) * 100 + day(createdAt)
        END AS diff
    FROM    (
        VALUES  (22, 2, 5589.39, N'2020-05-23 15:22:14.703')
        ,   (46, 2, 6103.08, N'2020-08-18 03:58:14.973')
        ,   (48, 2, 4905.96, N'2020-10-14 23:57:48.680')
        ,   (85, 2, 8953.03, N'2021-08-15 11:16:34.627')
        ,   (6, 2, 8132.46, N'2021-08-26 21:27:21.627')
        ,   (53, 2, 1913.24, N'2021-09-20 17:41:13.793')
        ,   (4, 2, 3164.81, N'2022-03-18 04:24:40.840')
        ,   (28, 2, 3506.16, N'2022-05-20 17:48:44.330')
        ,   (37, 2, 7256.73, N'2022-07-25 20:45:16.497')
        ,   (16, 2, 7470.38, N'2023-01-22 18:33:07.163')
        ,   (27, 2, 5957.58, N'2023-03-22 03:04:02.687')
        ,   (99, 2, 7722.43, N'2023-04-14 21:22:38.160')
        ,   (81, 2, 4517.39, N'2023-04-25 11:25:17.900')
        ,   (70, 2, 5562.04, N'2023-05-10 08:19:35.200')
        ,   (55, 2, 9343.17, N'2023-11-17 08:56:09.870')
        ,   (94, 2, 1056.38, N'2024-01-03 18:36:24.743')
        ,   (47, 2, 8434.11, N'2024-03-23 09:07:31.743')
        ,   (52, 4, 7502.97, N'2023-11-01 17:49:51.110')
        ,   (56, 4, 7337.75, N'2023-11-06 15:38:57.567')
        ,   (44, 4, 9385.97, N'2024-01-18 11:19:04.460')
        ,   (85, 1, 2718.66, N'2022-07-03 08:49:27.727')
        ,   (26, 1, 3832.69, N'2022-07-06 09:08:06.880')
        ,   (89, 1, 9569.85, N'2022-07-07 04:13:09.230')
        ,   (80, 1, 1523.62, N'2022-07-07 04:38:29.313')
        ,   (15, 1, 2500.21, N'2022-07-11 09:01:05.183')
        ,   (5, 1, 6874.03, N'2022-07-14 23:54:05.590')
        ,   (45, 1, 9188.03, N'2022-07-17 05:35:48.560')
        ,   (98, 1, 4426.17, N'2022-07-21 17:35:31.617')
        ,   (54, 1, 3862.86, N'2022-07-22 05:18:28.553')
        ,   (70, 1, 5668.82, N'2022-07-22 06:12:33.867')
        ,   (65, 1, 3653.67, N'2022-07-26 08:29:03.587')
    ) t (id,branchId,totalPrice,createdAt)
    ) x
GROUP BY branchid, diff

Not sure how you want to calculate the year diff, for example: 20231231 and 20240101 might differ by year or not depending on who you ask. Same with: 20240331 and 20240426 for months. So I went by 365 days, 28 days and the rest. You can probably adapt the case when to your needs.
Output:



branchid
total
dt




1
2718.66
2022-07-03


1
3832.69
2022-07-06


1
11093.47
2022-07-07


1
2500.21
2022-07-11


1
6874.03
2022-07-14


1
9188.03
2022-07-17


1
4426.17
2022-07-21


1
9531.68
2022-07-22


1
3653.67
2022-07-26


2
16598.43
2020-01-01


2
18998.73
2021-01-01


2
13927.7
2022-01-01


2
40572.99
2023-01-01


2
9490.49
2024-01-01


4
14840.72
2023-11-01


4
9385.97
2024-01-01




thank you, I have made an edit to the question if it might help

You supply the src query. The rest assumes a column called createdAt is available and calculates a CTE called report as output with a new column called dateBucket:
with src as (
    <your input data>
), bounds as (
    select branchId, min(createdAt) as minDt, max(createdAt) as maxDt
    from src group by branchId
), parameters as (
    select branchId,
        case when datediff(month, minDt, maxDt) = 0
             then 1 else 0 end as isDaily,
        case when datediff(year,  minDt, maxDt) = 0
             then 1 else 12 end as divisor,
        case when datediff(month, minDt, maxAt) = 0
             then cast(minDt as date)
             when datediff(year,  minDt, maxDt) = 0
             then datefromparts(year(minDt), month(minDt), 1)
             else datefromparts(year(minDt), 1, 1) end as baseDate
    from bounds
), report as (
    select *,
        case when isDaily = 1 then cast(createdAt as date)
             else dateadd(month,
                          datediff(month, baseDate, createdAt) / divisor * divisor,
                          baseDate) end as dateBucket
    from src s inner join join parameters p on p.branchId = s.branchId
)
select branchId, ..., dateBucket as timeframe
from report
group by branchId, ..., dateBucket
order by branchId, ..., timeframe;

or you may as well just take advantage of the datetrunc()/date_bucket() function if you have it:
with src as (
    <your input data>
), bounds as (
    select branchId, min(createdAt) as minDt, max(createdAt) as maxDt
    from src group by branchId
), parameters as (
    select branchId,
        case when datediff(month, minDt, maxDt) = 0 then 'D'
             when datediff(year,  minDt, maxDt) = 0 then 'M'
             else 'Y' end as bucketSize
    from bounds group by branchId
), report as (
    select *,
        case bucketSize when 'D' then datetrunc(day,   createdAt)
                        when 'M' then datetrunc(month, createdAt)
                        when 'Y' then datetrunc(year,  createdAt)
        end as dateBucket
    from src s inner join join parameters p on p.branchId = s.branchId
)
select branchId, ..., dateBucket as timeframe
from report
group by branchId, ..., dateBucket
order by branchId, ..., timeframe;

https://dbfiddle.uk/kACsQiPw

i got this answer with the help of @andrew https://dbfiddle.uk/Z2HvPd0j

@Raward, yeah, I saw you had accepted an answer. I would argue mine is cleaner and easier to follow, especially the second. it's also fairly reusable if you have other queries/report to create.
